# Is there a way to get MSMQ hard disk usage?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I have created few Message Queues and flooding in lot of messages into them but i want to stop the in flow once entire Msmq size reaches certain limit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's already a limit mechanism built into MSMQ - you don't have to implement it yourself. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785060(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Are you sending to local queues or across the network to remote queues?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Quota for the queue, this way you can set a maximum of space you want to allocate for the queue.

When you are writing to the queue, you will get an MessageQueueException with the message "Insufficient resources to perform operation" when the quota is maxed out.

If you want to read the quota from code, look at [MessageQueue.MaximumQueueSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.maximumqueuesize.aspx).

Comment: I tried setting MaximumQueueSize but once the limit is reached there is no signal (i'm expecting "Insufficient resources to perform operation" exception) from Message Queue.